# Unable to print to Samsung M2825ND on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, cups, samsung

I'm using the printer [Samsung M2825ND](https://www.samsung.com/us/computer/printers/SL-M2825DW/XAA-specs) in my home network. It worked great so far, as well as on Linux as on Windows, but since I re-installed Arch Linux on my laptop, I cannot print any longer.

Here's how I set it up:

I installed, activated and started cups and avahi:

```
pacman -S cups cups-filters ghostscript
systemctl enable org.cups.cupsd.service
systemctl start org.cups.cupsd.service

pacman -S nss-mdns
systemctl enable avahi-daemon.service
systemctl start avahi-daemon.service
```

In the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, I extended the line

```
hosts: files mymachines myhostname resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

to

```
hosts: files mymachines myhostname mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

as described on the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Avahi#Hostname_resolution).

Then I downloaded the [pxlmono-Samsung driver](https://openprinting.org/driver/pxlmono-Samsung), which I used earlier, and moved it to `/usr/share/cups/model/samsung.ppd`.

Then I figured out the parameters with `lpinfo`:

```
$ lpinfo -m | grep samsung
samsung.ppd Samsung M262x 282x Series PXL
driverless:ipp://samsung.local:631/ipp/print Samsung M262x 282x Series, driverless, cups-filters 1.21.2

$ sudo lpinfo -v
network ipp
network socket
network beh
network http
network https
network lpd
network ipps
network dnssd://samsung._printer._tcp.local/
network lpd://192.168.178.10/
network ipp://samsung.local:631/ipp/print
```

There are different network options, and since I always used dnssd so far, I configure it that way:

```
$ sudo lpadmin -p samsung -E -v 'dnssd://samsung._printer._tcp.local/' -m samsung.ppd
```

I set the printer as my default, use A4 as paper size and activate long-edge duplex printing:

```
$ lpoptions -d samsung
$ lpoptions -o PageSize=A4
$ lpoptions -o sides=two-sided-long-edge
$ lpoptions
device-uri=ipp://samsung._ipp._tcp.local/ PageSize=A4 printer-info=samsung printer-location printer-make-and-model='Samsung M262x 282x Series' printer-type=16810068 sides=two-sided-long-edge
```

But when I try to print a document using `lpr document.txt`, the file is just stuck in the queue with any other information.

How can I find the error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I download the generic `pxlmono` driver instead of the `pxlmono-Samsung` driver, it works perfectly as described.

Comment: If you use the native lpd hosted on Samsung printers, it doesn't need any driver on your computer. It's a simple data packet going through.